# Event works only one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I set event listener to button and expect new node adding every time the button is pressed, but, in fact, this works only one time. That must be my mistake with ":last" selector which somehow freezes on the same node. How can I fix this?

```
$("#btnAddWord").on('click', function(){
    $('div.input-group:last').after( inputGroup );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aT82W/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you try to add again and again the same element (instead of a new one). Let's create a new one for each click.

Modified code from your JSFiddle example:

```
$("#btnAddWord").on('click', function(){
    var inputGroup = document.createElement('div');
    inputGroup.setAttribute('class','input-group');
    inputGroup.innerHTML = '...here your HTML...';

    $('div.input-group:last').after( inputGroup );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a function that generates new input groups, here you're always referring to the same element (created one time only).

```
function createInputGroup() {
    return $('<div class="input-group">' +
             '<span class="input-group-addon">' +
             '  <input type="checkbox">' +
             '</span>' +
             '<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="New word">' +
             '<span class="input-group-addon">' +
             '  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>' +
             '</span>' +
             '</div>');
}

$("#btnAddWord").on('click', function(){
    $('div.input-group:last').after( createInputGroup() );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your fiddle link it seems that, inputGroup is no longer available on next click. so try this:

```
function CreateDiv()
{
      var inputGroup = document.createElement('div');
      inputGroup.setAttribute('class','input-group');
      inputGroup.innerHTML = '<span class="input-group-addon">'+
                       '  <input type="checkbox">'+
                       '</span>'+
                       '<input type="text" class="form-control" Placeholder="New word">'+
                       '<span class="input-group-addon">'+
                       '  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>'+
                       '</span>';
     return inputGroup;
}

$(document).on("click", "#btnAddWord", function(){ 
    $('div.input-group:last').after( CreateDiv() );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#btnAddWord").on('click', function(){
    var inputGroup = document.createElement('div');
inputGroup.setAttribute('class','input-group');
inputGroup.innerHTML = '<span class="input-group-addon">'+
                       '  <input type="checkbox">'+
                       '</span>'+
                       '<input type="text" class="form-control" Placeholder="New word">'+
                       '<span class="input-group-addon">'+
                       '  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>'+
                       '</span>';

    $('div.input-group').last().append( inputGroup );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you are just moving the same element from place to place (which is the same place by the way).

You need to clone this element by doing

`$(inputGroup).clone()`